# Wavefunction of a system of particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, particle-physics, electrons, wavefunction

A three-dimensional volume $V$ contains a certain number $N$ of electrons and they can't escape the volume $V$. Assume for simplicity that the potential $\mathcal{V}(\mathbf{r})$ is zero in all the volume. Each electron is in a stationary state, so with a well-defined energy value. The $k$-th electron has a wavefunction $\psi_k(\mathbf{r}, t)$ and an energy $E_k$, and obviously $k = 1, 2, \ldots, N$.

So,

$$i \hbar \displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \psi_k(\mathbf{r}, t) = E_k \psi_k(\mathbf{r}, t)$$

The *average* value of the energy of an electron in such a system has to be computed. I read about simple problems like the quantum well with a single electron, but never about multiple particles all in the same volume.

Is it legitimate to consider a *global* wavefunction

$$\psi (\mathbf{r}, t) = \sum_{k = 1}^N \psi_k(\mathbf{r}, t)$$

and then compute the average energy as

$$E_{av} = \displaystyle \frac{\displaystyle \int_V \psi^* (\mathbf{r}, t) i \hbar \displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \psi (\mathbf{r}, t) dV}{N} = \displaystyle \frac{\displaystyle \int_V \psi^* (\mathbf{r}, t) i \hbar \displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left[ \sum_{k = 1}^N \psi_k(\mathbf{r}, t) \right] dV}{N}$$

?

The result here would be

$$E_{av} = \displaystyle \frac{\displaystyle \int_V \psi^* (\mathbf{r}, t) \left[ \sum_{k = 1}^N E_k \psi_k(\mathbf{r}, t) \right] dV}{N} = \displaystyle \frac{\displaystyle \int_V \sum_{n = 1}^N \psi^*_n(\mathbf{r}, t) \left[ \sum_{k = 1}^N E_k \psi_k(\mathbf{r}, t) \right] dV}{N}$$

and knowing that $\psi^*_n(\mathbf{r}, t) \psi_k(\mathbf{r}, t) = 1$ if $n = k$ and $0$ for $n \neq k$ (these wavefunctions are orthonormal functions) trivially gives

$$E_{av} = \displaystyle \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^N E_k}{N}$$

Or another approach is required for such a problem?

For example, according to [this comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/249239/what-is-a-wave-function-in-simple-language#comment548528_249243), stating that «in a system with two electrons each individual electron would have its own wave function» «is wrong since they instead have a joint wave function». Is this the case also for this system of $N$ electrons?

Comment: Unfortunately, multi-particle wavefunctions are not simple sums of single-particle wavefunctions. It's much more complicated than that. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles for a few hints of how it works.

Comment: The correct way to approach the uniform electron gas is given in the Wiki article on [jellium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jellium); note how complex the Hamiltonian is. In practice, it's too complicated to solve analytically and instead requires heavy computational methods like [quantum Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Monte_Carlo) to solve.

Answer (score 4):

The way you combine quantum systems is not by *summing* their wavefunctions, but by taking the [*tensor product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces), see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54896/50583).

In particular, if the systems you are composing are just single electrons described by square-integrable wavefunctions in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathrm{d}x)$, then a system of $N$ electrons is described by a square-integrable function of *all* the $3N$ coordinates, i.e. an element in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{3N},\mathrm{d}x) = \bigoplus_{i=1}^N L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathrm{d}x)$. You have "individual wavefunctions" for the electrons if and only if the joint wavefunction $\psi(x_1,\dots,x_{3N})$ factors into the product of such individual wavefunctions, i.e.
$$ \psi(x_1,\dots,x_{3N}) = \psi(x_1,x_2,x_3)\cdot\psi(x_4,x_5,x_6)\cdot\dots\cdot\psi(x_{3N-2},x_{3N-1},x_{3N})$$